# In what circumstances would one use bit shifting operators in a for loops termination condition?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have been looking at [some code](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2013/03/03/replicating-wavetables/) that fills arrays with samples created using an IFFT (Inverse Fast Fourier Transform).

When the author iterates the array he uses an if construct that looks like this:

```
int idx;
for (idx = 1; idx < (tableLen >> 1); idx++) {
    freqWaveRe[idx] = 1.0 / idx;                    // sawtooth spectrum
    freqWaveRe[tableLen - idx] = -freqWaveRe[idx];  // mirror
}
```

Can you explain the terminating condition:

```
idx < (tableLen >> 1)
```

Why would you do something like this and what does it mean?

Comment: which they naturally followed with a post-increment. :D

Comment: Because `(tableLen >> 1)` looks more pro than `tableLen / 2`

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: It also has the questionable "advantage" of invoking undefined behaviour for negative values.

Comment: If my compiler can't decide the best method to divide by 2 better than I can, I'm done with C++. This is just bad code.

Comment: @jaggedSpire: Well, an `unsigned int` can hardly have a negative value ;-)

Comment: @David: Good point; it looks like C code to me actually.

Comment: C is not C++. Recommend to remove the C++ tag, as that seems to be C code. And: if you do not know what right shift does, You also should consult a C book (or C++, or Python, or Java, or ...)

Comment: The point is to confuse rookie/novice programmers, so the senior guy can have some job security.

Comment: Or it might be that the writer of this code is not much aware of compiler optimizations, so he wants to assure his code's speed. I'd rather take it this way. But then he should know that without compiler optimization, the shift operation will occur in each loop, so he should have saved `(tableLen >> 1)` in a temporary variable....

Comment: Once worked with a guy who always used `X=X<<3+X+X;` When stuff like this was brought up during code reviews, the response was usually, "If you can't read my code you should be working with me." Lost touch with him after he got fired.

Comment: Once upon a time, compilers were bad at optimizing. `a=b*0.33333` was faster than `a=b/3` and `a=b>>1` was much faster than `a=b/2`. Those times are gone, now compilers are much smarter than people.

Comment: @Olaf removed the c++ tag and grabbed the variable declaration, it is not unsigned in the code, it's an int.

Comment: So the answer is that it's a convenient way to iterate through half of the array? This would make sense as in general only the first half of an FFT result is used.

Comment: What's with the down votes and close votes? This is a legitimate question, unfortunately sometimes the programmer elite get on their high horse and won't step low enough to help someone who doesn't know as much as them.

Comment: So it will invoke undefined behaviour if `tableLen` happens to be be negative (I'm well aware that it might be unlikely judging by the name).

Comment: About the negative votes: No, this question is not legatimate. It shows no research at all (you could have simply read about C operators. The bitshift is a commonly used standard operator and can be found on Wikipedia and many other well know sites. As is the less-than comparison operator. Actually, it is hard to avoid it in most programs and many programming languages.

Comment: @Olaf, Stack Overflow aims to become the number one destination on the web for *every* programming question; even the ones that you know the answer to. Even if the answers can be found elsewhere by someone doing research having the answer here promotes the sites goal: To be the number one destination for programming questions.

Comment: There has to be some minimum standard. Otherwise SO will become twitter: hard to find useful answer among all the garbage questions. You can be expected to at least do minimal research, otherwise SO will become a tutorial site - which is not intended. Different from a tutorial, it cannot be structured due to its aim answering questions. And note that comments are not for discussion. If you have a problem with that, ask on meta. And note that - while I'm the only one answering now, I'm obviously not the only one to DV/CV - just thought it be polite to give you at least some hints.

Comment: @Olaf: just my take on it / why I've voted to keep open: the question may be legitimately C and C++, e.g. if the code is in some inline function in a header intended for both, so your removing the C++ tag was unwarranted.  With C++ in the picture, working out what `>>` does becomes much harder, as a beginner attempting research may be confused by overloaded use for e.g. I/O streaming.  The question asks "why?", and there's a simple concrete answer to that - it was historically an optimisation when bit-shifting opcodes executed faster than division, and optimisers couldn't be trusted.

Comment: @TonyD: 1) I just rquested removing the C++ tag. Please see the edit history, it was OP. 2) There is no language C/C++. I.a. for name mangling reasons you would have wrapped the part for C++ in `extern "C" { }`. 3) That has nothing to do why DV/CV 4) You cannot vote to "keep open" and there is currently no reopen vote. 5) **If** `>>` has been overloaded (a typical C++ nonsense), there would not be enough information anyway. 6) The question effectively asks what (**in C**) `<` and `>>` do. This you can find easier at Wikipedia than asking here. But maybe I'm old-school using my own wits...

Comment: @TonyD: And I disagree about the "optimization". This is also used to clarify bit 0 is not used here, e.g. if read from a variable with different bit-fields (not a bitfield struct, e.g. in embedded or driver programming.

Comment: @Olaf the code was in a C++ file, those guys use >> to direct streams? But I wasn't thinking that, I recognised the bit shift operator but it totally threw me, I'd never seen one in an if statement before. The whole thing confused me and I guess that's why I asked the question. Sometimes a bit of code feels out of my understanding, those DSP coders use little tricks all the time, I thought this might have been one of them. Now that it has been explained to me I recognise I could have worked it out. I still think the question should stand though. I'm not the only one that gets confused...

Comment: @AranMulholland: This generates a waveform-table, judging by the names, likely for signal synthesis or similar, so the `>>` has exactly the standard behaviour. And until now it **is** C. What would be the difference in which statement an expression is? And it is not in an `if` statement, but in a comparison-expression.

Comment: @Olaf, sorry I meant a for loop. And what would the difference be? Nothing, as you have pointed out. But it confused me, maybe because I've had my head down in the DSP code for a few days when I saw it it just did not compute.

Comment: You might have noticed that I did not correct the type of statement itself, but that it is part of an expression and that neither C nor C++ make a difference by statement for an expression. None supports that level of  meta-programming. And if you are into DSP code, you should be even mnore aware about this, because this is common practice. Anyway, you have the last word.

Comment: I'm not a great DSP programmer; the maths is beyond me most of the time. I'm starting a journey in that direction but I have a long way to go. My maths skills aren't that great and lots of it just looks like voodoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit shift operator used in this expression:

```
idx < (tableLen >> 1)
```

Terminates the for loop after iterating through the first half of the array. The right shift operator moves the value one bit to the right. Moving it one bit to the right divides it by two.

```
1010 in binary = 10
```

If we right shift it one bit we get:

```
0101 in binary = 5
```

A couple more things:

[Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony-d) mentioned some comments made that this 'will not work well if `idx` is negative'. Negative numbers are represented differently. Sometimes negatives are stored with the first bit representing the sign. If you shift the sign right you will lose that information and cause a bit of a mess.

[Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony-d) also said "it was historically an optimisation when bit-shifting opcodes executed faster than division, and optimisers couldn't be trusted"

Comment: As others have commented - but still worth mentioning in any answer - all that's true *if* the value is non-negative, as the identifier `tableLen` would imply.

Comment: Thanks @TonyD, excellent stuff